# Problem with prismatic joint and setForce function

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have 2 primastic joints that have to raise a ramp, but whenever i try to setForce() the joints i get the ramp raised for a split second and the joints go back to the original position. How do i make the force costant?

I was also reading about PID controllers but if i'm not mistaken there's no implementation to set force through them, is setVelocityTarget the right function to call for a prismatic joint? Thanks for the answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16264/problem-with-prismatic-joint-and-setforce-function/) by [lory18](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3258/lory18/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`SetForce()` sets the force for one time step only. It must be called every time step to keep applying a force. The [PID class](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cddf2613ce88d814cbe599aded96b356a5ffefd0/gazebo/common/PID.hh?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default) does the math for a PID controller, but doesn't call any methods to set forces. You'll need to calculate the error each time step and use the output of the [Update method](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cddf2613ce88d814cbe599aded96b356a5ffefd0/gazebo/common/PID.hh?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default#PID.hh-138) as the force.

If you want to control the velocity of joints there will soon be a tutorial about the different ways to do it: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/pull-requests/427/set-velocity-tutorial/diff

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lory18](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3258/lory18/) on 2017-05-23**:
Edit: i followed the tutorial and implemented two PID and setting the velocity target, it worked great thanks! now i just have one question, those PID will always try to set a force big enough to move anything on the ramp (given no limit in the sdf definition of the joints) or i have to set something else? Thanks for your time.
edit2: to be more specific, the ramp raises if i place a simple box of 1 kg but does not move if i set it to 200kg. Raising the P(ID) makes everything unstable.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-05-30**:
Unfortunately PID tuning is a bit of an art. I would try increasing IMax and I gain to allow a force to ramp up until it can lift the 200kg box.

**Comment by [lory18](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3258/lory18/) on 2017-05-30**:
eventually i found the right values, thanks!